# Where can I go to get a description of the many services that are avaialbe?

Tags: services

My subject line pretty much says it all.  I'm struggling as a newbie but am making progress.

Comment: The subject line doesn't say much.  What services?  The services on an Ubuntu machine?  The services on networking?  What services are you exactly talking about?

Comment: Programs that I can install or what I have read are called services in this forum.  Or are they called apps? Example: samba etc.

Comment: Not all the installed programs are services.

Comment: [Services tag](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/services) will explain, what is a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some applications (or packages in the Linux world) are things that can do word processing (such as libreoffice), web browsing (such as Iceweasel), or can do network file sharing (such as samba).  IF you want to get a list of what the packages do and you are on an Ubuntu install, you can go into the Software Center to browse through the packages in the repository.